# C# Snowflake command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the syntax for these two C# Snowflake commands.
Or where can i find it

```cs
using (var sfConn = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
{
    sfConn.ConnectionString = sConnectionString;
    sfConn.Open();
    var cmd = sfConn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "select top 100 * from RDW_SF.DM_LOAN.DIM_STD_MTHLY_DTM ;";
    SnowflakeDbCommand sfcmd = new SnowflakeDbCommand(sfConn.ConnectionString);
    SnowflakeDbCommandBuilder sf = new SnowflakeDbCommandBuilder(,)
    //  cmd.CommandText       = "select top 100 * from  RDW_SF.DM_LOAN.DIM_ACCT_CNTC;";
    // DWLoad_Load_DM_LOAN_DIM_STD_MTHLY_DTM)
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    Console.WriteLine("Retrieving rows from the Query");
    SnowflakeDbDataAdapter mySnowflakeDbDataAdapter = new SnowflakeDbDataAdapter(csfcmd);
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    mySnowflakeDbDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "RECS");
    sfConn.Close();
    DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables["RECS"];
    nCols = myDataTable.Columns.Count;
}
```

Comment: Corrected the code format

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for code examples, the [snowflake-connector-net repository carries test-cases](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/tree/master/Snowflake.Data.Tests) that exercise its features.

- Example of a [simple SnowflakeDbCommand](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/blob/d1effcc0e46a392dff862600cecd9ceaaa876ff0/Snowflake.Data.Tests/SFDbCommandIT.cs#L217-L233)
- Similar example, [with a DataReader](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/blob/d1effcc0e46a392dff862600cecd9ceaaa876ff0/Snowflake.Data.Tests/SFDbDataReaderIT.cs#L26-L52)
- A [DataSet and DbDataAdapter](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/blob/d1effcc0e46a392dff862600cecd9ceaaa876ff0/Snowflake.Data.Tests/SFDbAdaptorIT.cs#L18-L27) example

The Snowflake connector for .NET implements the standard and familiar [.NET System.Data interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data?view=netcore-3.1) so any example online that uses them (across database types) can be adapted for use with Snowflake with simple SQL-syntax changes (to conform to Snowflake's SQL).

If you're looking for examples on how to perform a connection, you can [find an example connection string here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/blame/d1effcc0e46a392dff862600cecd9ceaaa876ff0/README.md#L122-L133).

Comment: This is a huge help, Thanks Kirby