# Connection to snowflake database using C#

Tags: c#, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-connection, snowflake-schema

I'm new to snowflake database. I need to read the data from multiple tables  and do data mapping like sql tables.
I'm trying to get the data from table using the below code:
`

```
using (IDbConnection snowflakedb = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
{
      snowflakedb.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SnowFlakeParserConnection"].ConnectionString;
      snowflakedb.Open();
      var cmd = snowflakedb.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandText = "select * from EMAILPARSER_TABLE;";
      var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      dynamic accountList;
      while (reader.Read())
      {
         Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
         employeeList = reader.GetString(0);
      }
                
      snowflakedb.Close();
}
```

But its giving only single value- value of first row first column .How to read the entire row of the table? Later I also need to merge the data of two tables.

Also, When do we use snowflake ODBC driver connection:

```
var defaultConnection = _connectionFactory.GetOdbcConnection;
var snowflakeConnection = new OdbcConnection(defaultConnection.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: Your code only reads the first column - `reader.GetString(0);`

Answer (score 0):

As @stuartd says, you are getting one column because that is all your code is requesting. You may want to try something like this code from the [Github repo](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/blob/master/Snowflake.Data.Tests/SFDbDataReaderIT.cs)

```
 // All types except TIME fail conversion when calling GetTimeSpan
                for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        
                        ((SnowflakeDbDataReader)reader).GetTimeSpan(i);
                        Assert.Fail("Data should not be converted to TIME");
                    }
                    catch (SnowflakeDbException e)
                    {
                        Assert.AreEqual(270003, e.ErrorCode); 
                    }
                }
```

Also see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62523757/c-sharp-snowflake-command) for another approach using a data set.

As for when you should use the ODBC connection, consider using it as you would make that decision for any other database. One thing that has been noted before by other Snowflake developers is that the ODBC driver seems to be more strongly supported than the .Net driver.